# Execute Run/Debug Configuration on save

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a Run/Debug configuration in Intellij IDEA. It simply runs `cargo check` for my Rust project.

I'd like that configuration to run every time I save a file in my project.

I've investigated the File Watcher and Save Actions plugins and I don't think they support this.

Comment: A simple solution has been to make the configuration itself run a watch command but that's not what I'd like ideally.

Comment: What's the problem with the File Watcher?

Comment: Is there a way to run a configuration with File Watcher?

Comment: Do you need a run configuration or can you just run `cargo check` command line?

Comment: An actual Intellij configuration. I see how File Watcher works for arbitrary commands.

Comment: Why you can't use just the command to solve the original problem?

Comment: I can but there are niceties from the Intellij Run/Debug Configurations that I'd like to use. Also, I use those configurations when manually triggering them so I naturally want to reuse them.

Comment: I'm afraid, it's not possible at the moment. You can either write a plug-in or add this feature to the Save Actions plug-in which is open source.

Comment: Bummer! But that you for the clarification and answer.